# Why is the Quorum badge called that?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta

A quorum is a minimum number of people present for an assembly to be allowed to conduct business.

The quorum badge description says:

> One post with score of 2 on meta

I can't see any connection between that and posting a question here on Meta. The closest I can come up with is "being part of a group who discusses things", but that's a stretch. I feel like "Panelist" would convey that better without the extra minimum-number association.

Comment: *I always say...it's a crucible.*

Comment: A "quorum" also has the meaning of a select/chosen group, which seems to fit Meta pretty well. In Latin, it just means "of whom".

Comment: They had to name it something. Quorum sounded better than "meta-lurker".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even though there's a lot of people on Meta, it really only takes [a handful](https://xkcd.com/1070/) of people to take action or decide that action needs to be taken.

Hence, the word "quorum" seems appropriate; not everyone on Meta needs to agree (or Christ, nothing'd ever get done!), but at least [a few](https://xkcd.com/1070/) of us need to at least be on the same page.

Generally this applies to things like policy changes or clarifications, but different rules apply for feature requests and things that require Community Management input.